# SSHing into EC2 server via gives error Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Question as title.
Why is this, I have used the ssh command:
ssh -i mykey.pem root@xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
But i get that error, find nothing on google. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was confused by the poorly-punctuated error message: I tried logging in as "user" rather than "ec2-user".  Once I figured out that mistake, it worked fine.

Comment: when i try to log in as ec2_user, it asks me for the passwd, which, of course, i do not have -- as i know nothing about the AMI

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You log in as `ec2-user` as Klaus suggested:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@host
```

... and then you use `sudo` to run commands. E.g., to edit the `/etc/hosts` file which is owned by root and requires root privileges: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.

Or you run `sudo su` to become the `root` user.

Comment: Where is this written in Amazon docs? Couldn't find any info there.

Comment: http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonLinuxAMIUserGuide.pdf < first page, "Logging In"

Comment: when I run sudo su as the ec2-user, it asks for a password. I have set no password myself. something to do with sudoers file maybe ?

Comment: @littlecegian The PDF above says, the user has the rights. I am not sure why it doesn't work in your case. Maybe relaunch the instance and try again or ask support for help.

Answer (score 74):

By default `root` user is not allowed to login but you can use `ec2-user` as indicated by others.

Once you login with `ec2-user` you switch to `root` and change the SSH configuration.

To become the root user you run:

```
sudo su -
```

Edit the SSH daemon configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, e.g. by using vi, and replace the `PermitRootLogin` entry with the following:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Reload the SSH daemon configuration by running:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd reload
```

The message `Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.` is displayed because a command is executed when you login with the private key. To remove that command edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and remove the `command` option. The line should start with the key type (Eg. ssh-rsa).

(*) Do at your own risk. I recommend you to leave always a console open just in case you're not able to login after you make the configuration changes.

For reference you can read the man pages:

```
man sshd_config
man sshd
```

Comment: That is the answer I am expecting.  Thanks

Comment: inside /root/ssh/authorized_keys , The message Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user. is displayed because a command is executed when you login with the private key. To remove that command edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file and remove the command option. The line should start with the key type (Eg. ssh-rsa) +11111

Comment: "The message Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user. is displayed because a command is executed when you login with the private key. To remove that command edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file and remove the command option. The line should start with the key type (Eg. ssh-rsa)." This root cause clarification helps me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I have encountered a similar problem when setting up a hadoop cluster on Amazon ec2.

My head node needs to have root ssh access to each worker/slave nodes. I aliased the connects by adding each slave node's IP address, private address, and alias name to the `/etc/hosts/` file. (I get that data by running the command `` echo -e "`hostname -i`\t`hostname -f`\talias-name" `` where `alias-name` is what I call each node (`head` or `n1` for example). Then I put that output for each node in every node's `/etc/hosts` file.

The problem I have been encountering is that when I type ssh n1 while in my head node to ssh into my first slave node, I get that same error message: `Please login as the use "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".`
So after doing some research, I figured out how to fix it.

**First:**

- ssh into your server. non-root (ec2-user) access is fine here.
- Then    `su -` your way into root. Now `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and 
  un-comment the line `PermitRootLogin yes`.
- Exit vi editor.
- Now    restart ssh daemon by typing `service sshd stop` then `service
  sshd    start`.

**Second:**

- Now, here is the part I had to dig for,
- run `vi /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Comment out everything up to `ssh-rsa.` Just put a `#` at the beginning
  of the file's content, before `no-port-forwarding`... and hit enter on `ssh-rsa` to move it to
  the next line (this way you dont have to delete anything in case you
  want to backtrack).
- exit vi editor

Now you should be able to login to root without that error message popping up.

Also, if you are using aliases for a cluster setup; Repeat the same steps on each node. First ssh in using ec2-user then follow the steps.
After adding the IP address, private address, and alias name info to your `/etc/hosts` file you should be able to ssh into each node's root using the alias name for example `ssh n1`.

The tutorial I followed is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrxQXfE7t9A

But it didnt discuss the problem with root login.

Hope that helps! It worked for me.

*Keep in mind that I havnt taken any security into concern. This is simply a practice/dev setup.

Comment: thank you :) i needed to login as root to forward port 80 to my local machine, which i cannot do as ec2-user

Comment: Second step is the trick. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 9):

I think it's just asking you to login with another username. Do you happen to have a user called `ec2-user`? If so, try this instead:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: BUt if I then do this, I don't have user privilages, it asks me to log in as root

Comment: @Tom You change to the root account once you are logged in with the command `su -`

Comment: What if you want to automate this step and run root-privileged commands from a script ?

Comment: @OutputLogic use `su -` in the script you are invoking on the remote server?

Comment: @Klaus In my case if I want to rsync whole instance to my home pc, so I think the modifying authorized_keys file is only solution (for syncing files that "ubuntu\ec2-user" user has no access to them)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem when I tried to access my EC2 instance as 'root' through Windows PuTTY client, this is how I solved problem.

1. Access and edit SSH configuration file, to **allow root login** and **password authentication.**

   - Login as ec2-user (by default it is allowed)
   - Enter below command to open ssh config

     `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
   - Edit SSH configuration file as below using vi, [how to use vi editor](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html)

     ***PermitRootLogin yes***         (remove # at begging if it present)

     ***PasswordAuthentication yes***
2. Restart SSH

   `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart`
3. Change/set root password

   `sudo passwd root`

   type new password and re-enter it (at least 8 characters)
4. Exit current  session and close PuTTY

   `exit`
5. Try again login as root and type previously set password.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Try compare root key file and user key file)

*diff /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys*

...and see

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me that created a new user, copied root's .ssh dir to the new user, set ownership and STILL got this error - look at the new user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. It has SSH params specified that force the prompt. Delete everything from that line up to the ssh-rsa and you'll be good to go.

Or - copy /home/ec2-user/.ssh to the new user homedir instead of /root/.ssh

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -i mykey.pem root@xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

just replace above command to this

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

its working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and make sure this is set:

PasswordAuthentication yes

Then reload SSH:

systemctl reload sshd.service

You can now log in as users other than ec2-user.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a **single, simple line**:

```
sudo ssh -i ./mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-x-xx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Note that, you can get the line after the `@` from the `Public IPv4 DNS` section in your instance summary page.