# ssh : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, centos, gitlab

i'm use centos 5.9.
after installing gitlab by this [link](https://github.com/zzhgjmh/gitlab-centos/blob/master/gitlab-centos5.9.sh) ssh not working.
before install gitlab ssh correctly working.
i'm using this server localy and other services such as elastix and apache,mysql installed on server.

appeare this error :

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.88.23 [192.168.88.23] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
                                        debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.88.23:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 3111/6144
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:7J6JOe94H9PedNKlx6yG/wMy6ZYC8iB74WdOVGDgY7A
debug1: Host '192.168.88.23' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 3102/6144
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: please add `stackTrace` donot attach Pics

Comment: removed picture :)

Comment: I also had unspecified GSS failure, making my ssh connection slower. Commenting GSSAPIAuthentication no GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config solved my problem

Answer (score 76):

Setting 700 to .ssh and 600 to authorized_keys solved the issue.

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: This worked for me while keeping PasswordAuthentication no. I had 660 on the authorized_keys file previously, which was too open

Comment: this solved my issue! i copied authorized keys to an alternative user (ec2-user is too obvious these days) and fixed permissions!

Answer (score 57):

I had the same issue while using vagrant.  So from my Mac I was trying to ssh to a vagrant box (CentOS 7)

Solved it by amending the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `PasswordAuthentication yes` then re-started the service using `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hero. Thanks for this.

Comment: not sure why this is an answer if it is what i think it is.  i mean the error is being caused,  when im tryig log in with key.  i dont want a password.

Comment: In my case it was need to set ChallengeResponseAuthentication  yes.

Answer (score 32):

Setting PasswordAuthentication to yes,  is not the best way to go , 
is not as secure as using private and public keys for authentication !

First make sure that that you have the fallowing permissions set, on the server side.

First check your home dir (SERVER SIDE)

```
[vini@random ~]$ ls -ld ~

drwx------. 3 vini vini 127 Nov 23 15:29 /home/vini
```

if it is not like this, run

```
chmod 0700 /home/your_home
```

Now check .ssh folder

```
[vini@random ~]$ ls -ld  /home/vini/.ssh/

drwx------. 2 vini vini 29 Nov 23 15:28 /home/vini/.ssh/
```

if it is not looking like this, run

```
chmod 0700 /home/your_home/.ssh
```

now make sure that `authorized_keys` looks like this

```
[vini@venon ~]$ ls -ld  /home/vini/.ssh/authorized_keys 

-rw-------. 1 vini vini 393 Nov 23 15:28 /home/vini/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or just run

```
chmod 0600 /home/your_home/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After that go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

For best security set

```
PermitRootLogin no

PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

keep as `yes` for testing purposes

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Make sure that

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment those lines for GSSAPI

```
# #GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# #GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
```

Make sure that is set to `UsePAM yes`

```
UsePAM yes
```

now restart sshd service

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

on the client side

```
cd /home/your_home/.ssh
```

generate new keys; setting a password is optional but is a good idea

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

copy pub key to your server

```
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub user_name@server_ip 

start ssh agent 

eval $(ssh-agent)

ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/your_private_key
```

now your are good to go !

```
ssh user_name@server_ip
```

if everything works just fine

make a backup of your private key and then deny `PasswordAuthentication`

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Restart you server

now anyone trying to ssh into  your server, without your keys  should get

```
vini@random: Permission denied (publickey).
```

keep script kids away from your business, and good luck

Comment: Should the following changes be made on server side? `PermitRootLogin no`, `PubkeyAuthentication yes`, `PasswordAuthentication yes`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`, `#GSSAPIAuthentication yes`, `#GSSAPICleanupCredentials no`, `UsePAM yes`

Comment: Yes, @deesolie. It is on serverside.

Comment: Thank you, @vini and @Das_Geek. My issue was `/home/skg/.ssh/authorized_keys` file permissions, it was `664`. Changed it to `0600`, then it worked. `sudo chmod 0600 /home/skg/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: even after years, this is the best answer for ssh problems

Comment: I get to `ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub user_name@server_ip` and get back `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
media-server@xxx.xxx.x.xx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

I don't ever get prompted for a password

Answer (score 19):

The isssue is the username for most publickey errors on centos instances on AWS.
For Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic):

**its pretty simple. Just change your username from centos to ec2-user and the issue is solved.**

Thank me later :)

Comment: This was the issue for me. In my Mac I was logging as root and as soon as I changed to ec2-user, it worked.

Comment: I made this mistake

Comment: In my case the error was the opposite I had to use centos instead of ec2-user, thank you because this made me try it

Answer (score 18):

As everybody else has already said you need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

I ran into this problem setting up a Vagrant box - so therefore it makes sense to script this and do it automatically in a shell provisioner:

`sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;`

`sudo systemctl restart sshd;`

Comment: Just FYI the given error is irrelevant to password authentication.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. In my case, macOS doesn't load my SSH keys, but I fix it with:

```
ssh-add <SSH private key>
ssh-add <SSH public key>
```

I couldn't connect to a Droplet on DigitalOcean, but the subsequent commands work for me.

You can go to the forum [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-failed-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic).

Answer (score 7):

please make sure following changes should be uncommented, which I did and got succeed in centos7

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

1.PubkeyAuthentication yes

2.PasswordAuthentication yes

3.GSSAPIKeyExchange no

4.GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

systemctl restart sshd

ssh-keygen

chmod 777 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 

ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ipaddress
```

thank you all and good luck

Answer (score 5):

According to the line `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic` , ssh password authentication is disabled and apparently you are not using public key authentication.

Login to your server using console and open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file  with an editor with root user and look for line `PasswordAuthentication` then set it's value to yes and finally restart sshd service.

Comment: If you login as `root` , look for `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and see is it set to `yes` or not.

Comment: but this is not change !

Answer (score 5):

Tried a lot of things, it did not help.

It get access in a simple way:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
killall ssh-agent
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

Note that at the end of the `ssh-add -L` output must be not a path to the key, but your email.

Answer (score 3):

In Centos 7

Error : publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic

Ans : Root access to vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change the PasswordAuthentication ( no ) to yes.

2 . Restart the sshd services

root> systemctl restart sshd.service

3. Logon into local id via putty without key.

Answer (score 3):

As a few others have mentioned, make sure you are using the right private key when you ssh into your server. I had multiple ssh private keys set up in my directory, so it was defaulting to a different key. To ssh with the correct key call it out in your CLI call `ssh centos@IP-ADDRESS -i YOUR-PATH-TO-KEY`, in my case the path was `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has mention this in. above answers so i am mentioning it.

This error can also come if you're in the wrong folder or path of your pem file is not correct. I was having similar issue and found that my pem file was not there from where i am executing the ssh command

```
cd KeyPair
ssh -i Keypair.pem ec2-user@244.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd add my fix in the pot.

I was getting the same error trying to connect to Amazon Linux from Ubuntu. The solution was to simply change this:

```
ssh-add -c <key_location>.pem
```

to this:

```
ssh-add "<key_location>.pem"
```

... pretty simple change there got me in.

Comment: -c          Require confirmation to sign using identities

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are missing the correct id_rsa key set up in authorized_keys for an AWS instance.

Exact error I got (this article came up when I googled the error):

`ec2-user@X.X.X.X: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Note: If you have many keys, you have to either specify the key on the ssh command line or else add it to you ssh-agent keys (see ssh-add -l). Only the first 6 keys from ssh-agent may work - the default sshd MaxAuthTries config value is 6.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic) earlier.

I had to go /etc/ssh/sshd_config to add the user user into AllowUsers section, then restarted sshd service.

Answer (score 1):

I know this reply is drowned into the abyss of answers, but I think it's still relevant to share my team's use case : the error can also be triggered because the target instance is incorrect.
As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by setting GSSAPIAuthentication to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should assign the public key to the `authorized_keys`, the simple way to do this is using `ssh-copy-id -i your-pub-key-file user@dest`.

Answer (score 0):

And I think this will clearify the cause of posted problem, actualy this is bug of pssh itself (contains inside "askpass-client.py"). It is pssh's lib file. And there is documented issue for -A case:
**https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/issues/80**
There are two possible resolutions to use version of pssh containing this bug in case you forced to use passphrase for private key access:

1. Correct your "askpass-client.py" as described in link listed before in my post.
2. Using your favorite pass keeper.

**Thnks for attention, hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

I try

```sh
rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then it work!

Comment: It works for me, too. For me, private and public key pair were not matched each other. Thank you for saving my time!

Answer (score 0):

First a password login has to be established to remote machine

- Firstly make a password login

you have to enable a password login by enabling the property ie) **PasswordAuthentication yes** in sshd_config file.Then restart the sshd service and copy the pub key to remote server (aws ec2 in my case), key will be copied without any error

- Without password login works if and only if password login is made first
- copy the pub key contents to authorised keys, cat xxx.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help someone. Problem I encountered is, I was completely using wrong key with the IP. Make sure you are using the right key for the right IP

Answer (score 0):

For me it is a completely mistake, someone copy paste the key into the same row with another key, after separating them into two different lines then it works again, so check if your authorized_key file has similar mistakes !

Answer (score 0):

Let me share with you how I did it and I am sure you will find good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230516/sshing-into-ec2-server-via-gives-error-please-login-as-the-ec2-user-user-rather).

Make sure the following

> Step 1. You have `Public DNS (IPv4) from aws`   E.g ec2-IPV4.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

> Step 2. You remember where your `your_secret_key_is.pem`  E.g its better to keep it far from root of the known folders like Downloads, Desktop or Documents

> Step 3 Open terminal and add the command `sudo ssh -v -i path-to-key.pem ec2-user@host`

**ec2-user** is important because it for some linux server it is the username

**sudo** it needs permission to execute

**host** It is Amazon Public DNS (IPv4) (copy step 1)

Find more info [here](https://jmaicaaan.medium.com/this-is-how-i-deploy-my-first-nestjs-application-into-aws-ec2-a9eab0ccf020)

Comment: That's not even a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

seems like an issue generated by the ssh client rather than the ssh server in my case.
Here's what caused my problem and how I solved.
The problem source is I used `sudo` to generate the keys like this:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/serverA_ed25519_key
```

This automatically set the owner of these key files to root only, so my current user doesn't have permission to read the keys.

Now solution #1 is change the file ownership to your current user. This's what I did.

```
sudo chown CURRENT_USER ~/.ssh/serverA_ed25519_key
```

Solution #2 would be just run ssh client with `sudo` when you try to connect to the ssh server.

Finally, a trick to find the source of problem with ssh client.

```
ssh -v -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/serverA_ed25519_key me@serverA
```

This let me focus on the problem by:

- show verbose info by `-v` flag.
- the `-o` option and `-i ~/.ssh/serverA_ed25519_key` force ssh client to try with this key ONLY, not all the keys you have.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this error info : `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Using cmd: `ssh -i "~/.ssh/old.pem" user@ip` cause the error.

Problem is `old.pem` has been deprecated， after changing to newest pem file，
the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using wrong username. Fixed that and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple, the owner for the key should be one in case if windows ( Just remove other users and keep only one or deny other users permissions) for linux/Mac just do a chmod 400 as this will only give read permission only to the user and no permission to groups or public.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this strange error whiles connecting from my Mac(host) to a CentOS(7.9) guest. I had to explicitly passed the key file to the `ssh` client `ssh root@ip -i private_key_file` before connection was successful.

Earlier on, I had enabled the following after the usual key generation with `ssh-keygen` and copying with `ssh-copy-id`

> PermitRootLogin yes #Logging in with root, it was set by default
> PasswordAuthentication no

I decided against using the default name provided by `ssh-keygen` though the generated file was saved at the same location as the default.

I left the other default values untouched.
Don't forget to restart sshd on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I got Sucess !!
I've copied my ssh_keys from my other machine and tryed to log to my AWS EC2, but it failed:

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/xxxx/.ssh/my_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
ec2-user@bla-blah-blah.zzzzz.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

The solution was:

cd $HOME/.ssh

ls -l

-r-x------ 1 xxxx xxxx 1766 May  4 09:13 id_rsa

-r-x------ 1 xxxx xxxx  405 May  4 09:13 id_rsa.pub

-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx  444 May  6 17:18 known_hosts

Optional command:
rm known_hosts

**chmod 400 id***

ssh -i ./id_rsa.pub ec2-user@bla-blah-blah.zzzzz.amazonaws.com

Last login: Fri May  6 19:09:48 2022 from 123.456.77.9

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
  ___|\___|___|
```

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: It sets the keys permissions only to read and execute  (not write) for the file owner.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this to add your key to localhost of current user.

```
 ssh-copy-id localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was selinux.
It was just disabling it.

vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=**disabled**

setenforce 0;

sestatus;

Answer (score 0):

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone 
This will help debug the issues by printing a detailed log.

Answer (score 0):

For me running the ssh command with sudo worked try it once

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple actually when you generate your SSH keys, you should copy past it in both autorised_key & public_rsa.id on ur server.
this is will solve ur probelm.
I m using bitbucket pipeline with AWS EC2 instance.