# Unable to vagrant ssh after moving Virtualbox folder

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, openssh

Here is a messy situation:

I have a Vagrant VM, but after noticing that the corresponding Virtualbox folder

`~/VirtualBox VMs/thevbfolder`

grew too much, I relocated it by copying it in another place.

I also deleted the VM from Virtualbox GUI.

I then re-created a new VM (using VB GUI) and used the existing disk (.vdi) (which was copied alongside the entire VB folder to a new place).

The issue is that I seem to be now locked out of the machine (in terms of Vagrant).

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...


$ ssh vagrant@thehostname
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

$ ssh root@dmsnl857-vm
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

p.s. when the machine was in good state, I created a password for the root account also.

**update**: by following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635200/2409793), I managed to make the explicit ssh work.

However, during `vagrant up` (which I assume it tries to perform a private key based auth) I still get `Authentication failure`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I had the same issue today - the error message looks to me like a straight ssh config issue: ssh with password authentication has been disabled. If it is you can fix it by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the target server and ensuring that the following config value is present and uncommented `PasswordAuthentication yes`. If you change the value you'll need to restart `sshd`: `service sshd restart` (for CentOS/RedHat 6)

Comment: I did that plus I do a ssh-copy-id to push my public key dans replace vagrante private generated key with my private key and it's work.