# user@<ip address> : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I did this command `ssh -i EC2tutorial.pem user@<ip addresss>` and it is showing only this error `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` and nothing more
what do i do

Comment: How you generated key pair? Also did you add your public key to server ?

Comment: I am following the AWS tutorial by udemy, they didnt mention any such thing, the key pair  is generated automatically and downloaded by the name ```EC2tutorial.pem```, can you suggest anything based on this info, i am fairly new at this @ArchilLabadze

Comment: Just have doubts that .pen won’t work it needs some conversation to private key

Comment: seems like you might be missing the correct permissions on the downloaded key which should be 600. you might wanna go through this post [ssh : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300446/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-with-mic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thought ec2-user is the username of the tutor's machine so I used mine, but after using `ec2-user@<ipaddress>`, it worked here are some referal links if someone needs it in future ->
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-2-connect-to-instance.html#sshclient

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are running the command where you have your **EC2tutorial.pem**
2. If you are in C drive location, this should ideally work.
3. If you are NOT in C drive location, then you need to remove any permissions for other users or groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was a conflict with the file.pem's permissions.

```
cd path/of/your/file.pem/directory
```

```
chmod 0400 EC2Tutorial.pem
```

```
ssh -i EC2Tutorial.pem ec2-user@<PublicIPv4address>
```

Then, it worked like a charm.